# FFMPEG commands on JavaScript

Tags: javascript, node.js, ffmpeg

I am Recording audio in .pcm format and I want it to convert it into .wav
Using CMD ffmpeg commands

```
ffmpeg -f s16le -ar 44.1k -ac 2 -i input.pcm output.wav
```

But I want to do it through JavaScript simultaneously,

I have Tried This:

```
const ffmpeg = require('child_process').exec
        let input = './audio/input.pcm';
        let output = './audio/output.wav';

        ffmpeg(`ffmpeg -f s16le -ar 44.1k -ac 2 -i ${input} ${output}`)
```

This is giving me output.wav but it is not proper output

1 issue That I observed is that if my input.pcm is of 600KB but my output.wav is 90KB
So, its not converting it properly... How can I fix this ????

Thanks in Advance

Comment: Remember to escape your `input` and `output` names!

Comment: Are you sure you're doing an identical command? Do you have to wait for it to complete?

Comment: I Guess I have to wait, I think the process is not getting rendered completely and terminal gets killed before that. . . How can I Fix this ? `setTimeout()` ?

Comment: You have to wait for the `close` event.

Comment: Sorry, but I didn't get it ?

Comment: This is [standard Node.js event listening with the `on()` function](https://nodejs.org/api/events.html).